# Cant call event on dynamically created elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic-data

I am creating a Row of elements where in my ROW i have a select box/Drop Down. What i want is that i want to call **onChange** function on every Drop Down on Every row.

```
count = 1;
jQuery('select[id="warehouse-' + count + '"]').change(function() {
    alert('hello');
    var urlWareHouse = "<?php echo $this->url('stock', array('action' => 'populateLocationInWarehouse', 'controller' => 'Stock')) ?>";
    url = urlWareHouse + '/' + jQuery('id="warehouse-' + count + '"]').val();
    SelectBoxNullValue = "Select Location";
    populateSelectBox(url, 'warehouse-'+count, 'location');
    count++;
});
```

My **populateSelectBox** function is simply an ajax call that populates data to newly created Select Element.
I dont know what i am doing wrong. The thing is i cannot trigger **onChange** on newly created with my Approach.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-8) method in the API? This used to be accomplished with `.live()` but has since been deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind to elements even new ones, otherwsie you have to continuously rebind the element.

```
jQuery(document).on("change",'select[id="warehouse-' + count + '"]',function() {
    alert('hello');
    var urlWareHouse = "<?php echo $this->url('stock', array('action' => 'populateLocationInWarehouse', 'controller' => 'Stock')) ?>";
    url = urlWareHouse + '/' + jQuery('id="warehouse-' + count + '"]').val();
    SelectBoxNullValue = "Select Location";
    populateSelectBox(url, 'warehouse-'+count, 'location');
    count++;
});
```

Comment: I have small question here. This code is helping for only 1st row. I mean event is attaching to only 1st occurrence of call and not to any other can you tell why is it happening so?

Comment: @noobie-php Your selector is probably not correct, it looks like you have a id that has warehouse- and then some number, i assume the number increases in some way, try using `'select[id^=warehouse-]'` it will select any selectbox that has a id starting with `warehouse-`

Answer (score 2):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), instead of .change().

**.change** only binds once. If an element is added it needs to be re-bound. **.on** does this automatically.

Also, since you have an ID, you don't need to specify "select" as part of your selector.

`jQuery('#warehouse-' + count)` will do.

Comment: thx for reply, just a qucik question you mentioned that .change() binds only 1 time. Can i use it For further for 1st event, i mean use it all the way, Dont use onChange At all

Comment: Let me re-phrase: It binds permanently (every click), but not if the element is added/removed from the DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: you mean that element for which the element is called on (Parent element lets say), Or all the elements? From all i mean elements that are added to the DOM using JS

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @moobie-php binds work on all matching elements that match your selector, but only if they currently are in the DOM, hence why you have to use `on`, it will bind the event to new elements but only if they match the selector.